# The output of the code is in different order than expected

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, output

```
n = int(input())  
a_name = []  
a_score = []  
for _ in range(n):  
  name = input()  
  score = float(input())  
  a_name.append(name)  
  a_score.append(score)  
a_score1 = set(a_score)  
a_score1.remove(min(a_score1))  
x = min(a_score1)  
for i in range(n):  
    if a_score[i]==x:  
        print(a_name[i])
```

For the following code input is:
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39

My Output:
Harry
Berry

Expected Output:
Berry
Harry

I am a newbie in the programming world and would appreciate help to solve this.
This is a hacker rank problem and the problem is to find the names with a second minimum score. I was able to pass 8/10 test cases but 2 test cases are failing with this solution. I am able to find the correct names(i.e. names with second-lowest score) however it is printed in wrong order)

Comment: Hi Saloni, welcome to SO! Is there a particular reason why you're converting the tuple to a set?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. Please [edit] your question to have a descriptive title. Now onto the problem, what is the expected order? You've got them in order of occurence, which is wrong apparently. Are they supposed to be sorted?

Comment: Hi Joseph,  I am still trying to learn about Python. I was trying to find the second minimum value and wanted to remove the first minimum. This was my way of doing it. Feel free to correct if anything that's not necessary

Comment: @wjandrea I will edit the title. Umm the problem does not state if it needs to be sorted or not. The problem was to find the second minimum score and print the names of people with second minimum score. I was successful in finding the correct names but the hacker rank solution have a different order of names than the ones I have printed.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using two lists instead of a dict?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I am still learning python and not very handy with dict and hence started with lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
a_name = []
a_score = []
for _ in range(n):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    a_name.append(name)
    a_score.append(score)
a_score1 = set(a_score)
a_score1.remove(min(a_score1))
x = min(a_score1)
y =[]
for i in range(n):
    if a_score[i]==x:
        y.append(a_name[i])
y.sort()
for j in range(len(y)):
    print(y[j])
```

I got the output with this code. Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can find first the second minim and then find the names that have the second minim using a list comprehension and the built-in function [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
second_minim = sorted(a_score)[1]
[n for n, s in zip(a_name, a_score) if s == second_minim]
```

output:

```
['Harry', 'Berry']
```

---

related to why should be `['Berry', 'Harry']` instead of `['Harry', 'Berry']` according to the [requirements](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem) that you pointed:

> If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line

so you should use:

```
result = sorted(n for n, s in zip(a_name, a_score) if s == second_minim)

print(*result, sep='\n')
```

output:

```
Berry
Harry
```

Comment: Exactly the problem. The output is Harry Berry and expected is Berry Harry

Comment: @SaloniShah why should be Herry Berry? and why the order should matter?

Comment: This is a hacker rank problem please see the link to the problem. I have no idea why the order matters but I guess this is how hacker rank works and may be because its a nested list problem.  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem

Comment: @SaloniShah check my answer

Comment: Okay let me try this. I think I understood what was done here. But can you please explain? I have not used zip() before.

Comment: @SaloniShah there is a link to the documentation to find more about zip,

Comment: if you have `list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))` this will return `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`

Comment: I tried something different and posted as an answer. But I was able to understand what I needed to do after looking at your answer. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using two lists, you can map the scores to a name with a dict. Like so:

```
scores_dict = {'Harry': 37.21,
          'Berry': 37.21,
          'Tina': 37.2,
          'Akriti': 41,
          'Harsh': 39
          }
```

Next remove all matching keys to the starting min value so that we can get the second min

```
x = min(scores_dict, key=scores_dict.get)
filtered_scores = {k:v for k,v in scores_dict.items() if v != scores_dict[x]}
```

Then we grab all the keys of any of the new min value.

```
x = min(filtered_scores, key=scores_dict.get)
res = [key for key in filtered_scores if filtered_scores[key] == filtered_scores[x]]
```

## Full Code

```
n = int(input)
scores_dict = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name = input()
    score = int(input())
    scores_dict[name] = score

# The loop will produce this dict
'''
scores_dict = {'Harry': 37.21,
          'Berry': 37.21,
          'Tina': 37.2,
          'Akriti': 41,
          'Harsh': 39
          }
'''

x = min(scores_dict, key=scores_dict.get)
filtered_scores = {k:v for k,v in scores_dict.items() if v != scores_dict[x]}

x = min(filtered_scores, key=scores_dict.get)
res = [key for key in filtered_scores if filtered_scores[key] == filtered_scores[x]]

print(res)
```

If you really want to use two lists, it can be done, but it adds potential for bugs by adding unneeded complexity.

Dictionaries are just associative (named) arrays (lists).

Comment: How to find second minimum score using dict?

Comment: @SaloniShah I didn't see second. Sorry I'll edit my answer